# How print from android device to windows network shared printer?

Tags: android, networking, printing

I have a Printer which is connected to a windows 7 machine via a USB cable and operates on Usb001 port.Printer is shared across the network, any user on the network can print from their system successfully.The printer does not have an Ethernet port.

My requirement is to print a doc from android device to the locally shared network printer.is it possible? if yes please give some examples or guidance.

NOTE : I do not want to go with Google cloud printing, and i have tried using sockets but i think it is not possible without a Ethernet port.

I also looked into the Print Manager API introduced in Android API 19 and above,but i did not understand the proper functionality of that api,which type of printer can be used with these api?

Please give some info and guide me solve my issue, thank u for consideration.

Comment: Hi Darwin I am also looking for same did you found any solution ?

Comment: I am not able to find a solution, its better u may create a desktop application for printing feature and send data to that app from android using web service

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

The PrintManager api does not provide a way to discover or connect to printers by itself, it instead communicates with the [PrintService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrintService.html)s installed on the device. Your app's user will need to install a [Print service plugin](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=print%20service%20plugin&hl=en) if there isn't one on the device by default. The type of connection to the printer depends on the print service used.